# Bootstrap Thumbnail Gallery skips first image

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, sql-server-2008

I'm loading the gallery progmatically using C# and sql.
Everything is fine on the query side
Here is my sample query
and its results:

```
SELECT productName,productType,image_desc
                               FROM Products3
                               WHERE productType = 'Souvenirs'
```

The results would be like this
[image]

But if I use this query along with my c# codes. `Button Pins` does not appear it is being skipped.

```
    private void load_souvenirs_products()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT productName,productType,image_desc
                               FROM Products3
                               WHERE productType = 'Souvenirs'", con);

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


        if (rdr.Read())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                product_name = rdr["productName"].ToString();
                product_type = rdr["productType"].ToString();
                image_desc = rdr["image_desc"].ToString();

                // foreach()

                lbl_table.Text += @"<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb'>
                    <a href='\CustomerFiles\TermsPDF\Terms_and_Conditions_Order_Form.pdf' download>
                        <p><small>" + product_name + @"</small></p>
                        <img class='img-responsive' src='../../Images/ProductImage/" + image_desc + @"' alt=''>
                    </a>
                </div>";

            }
        }

        con.Close();
    }
```

This query should load all data that has `productType` of **Souvenirs**.

Here is my current output:
[image]

Where did I go wrong?Because this happens on all my **Product List** as well.All first Row being skip.

I'm following [this](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/thumbnail-gallery/) example for bootstrap gallery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your while loop is nested inside the if statement, you're essentially calling rdr.Read twice before accessing the data.  This means the first row of the returned results is always skipped.

You should get rid of the if statement and just use the while loop.

Comment: I see.Going to try it.